# ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' 2,019,278 ' - potentially illegal character or format?

Tags: numpy

I am having an issue with a format conversion from object to 'float64'. I cannot perform any matrix operations until this conversion occurs and in general this is a major annoyance because I am getting caught up in the weeds...

Potentially it has to do with the inclusion of a space or a space and an apostrophe in the array in the original format.

**The original array looks like this:**

```
array([[' 2,019,278 ', ' 14,569,743 ', ' 14,116,057 ', ' 30,705,078 '],
   [' 514,049 ', ' 3,301,330 ', ' 1,775,624 ', ' 5,591,003 '],
   [' 40,364 ', ' 283,894 ', ' 138,342 ', ' 462,600 '],
   [' 77,849 ', ' 528,504 ', ' 665,829 ', ' 1,272,182 '],
   [' 4,534 ', ' 39,282 ', ' 23,902 ', ' 67,718 '],
   [' 182,313 ', ' 795,102 ', ' 369,981 ', ' 1,347,396 '],
   [' 256,867 ', ' 694,895 ', ' 240,025 ', ' 1,191,787 '],
   [' 1,527,829 ', ' 12,690,612 ', ' 12,968,625 ', ' 27,187,066 '],
   [' 771,142 ', ' 2,937,748 ', ' 1,612,082 ', ' 5,320,972 ']],
  dtype=object)
```

**My code looks like this:**

```
a = pd.DataFrame.to_numpy(df_By_Race_Disability, dtype=None, copy=False)
a = a.astype('float64')
```

**This is the error I receive:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-ba9570a13fdd> in <module>
      1 a = pd.DataFrame.to_numpy(df_By_Race_Disability, dtype=None, copy=False)
      2 #b = pd.DataFrame.to_numpy(df_By_Race_Total, dtype=None, copy=False)
----> 3 a = a.astype('float64')
      4 #b = b.astype('float64')
      5 #b = np.reciprocal(b)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' 2,019,278 '
```

Comment: The commas `,` in the strings are creating the problem, try replacing the commas using `.apply()` and then convert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do first this:

```
df_temp = df_By_Race_Disability.applymap(lambda x: x.replace(',', ''))
```

Then you can continue with your code

```
a = pd.DataFrame.to_numpy(df_temp, dtype=None, copy=False)
a = a.astype('float64')
```